# Css3 animation delay with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, delay, css-animations

I am using scroll animations. I'm using `animate.css` library and `viewport.js`. It's clearly working. But I want to dynamically add animation delays. For example: I have social media icon list and I want to delay the animation for each item.

This is my JS code:

```
$(".animateda:in-viewport(-10)").find(".animated").each(function(queue) {
    $(this).addClass($(this).attr("data-animation"));
});
```

I can do it by writing a CSS class for each delay:

```
.animate-delay-1{animation-duration:.6s;animation-delay:.3s}
.animate-delay-2{animation-duration:.6s;animation-delay:.6s}.....
```

And use this JS code:

```
$(this).find(".animated-item").each(function(queue) {
    $(this).addClass("animate-delay-"+(queue+1)).addClass($(this).attr("data-animation"));
});
```

It's working good. But I must write a CSS delay class for all of the objects that have a animation. Can I make the delays with jQuery without using different CSS classes for each object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) function.

`setTimeout` takes two arguments, a callback function and a delay in ms. If you wanted to delay the adding of a class by 6 seconds, you could do something like this:

```
var delay = 6000;
$(".animateda:in-viewport(-10)").find(".animated").each(function(queue) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // do some animation here
    }, delay);
});
```

This would do the animation ([roughly](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/)) six seconds after it was called.

**EDIT:** If you wanted to change the length of the animation each time, you could do something like this:  *The setTimeout must be wrapped in a closure, to stop the value of i changing within the method.*

```
var i = 0;
$(".animateda:in-viewport(-10)").find(".animated").each(function(queue) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // do some animation here
        }, i * 350);
    })(i);
    i++; // increment i for each item
});
```

Comment: Ok but this is adding all items delay. I want to make it
1.item 3s delay 2.item 6s delay 3.item 9s delay...

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to be a little clearer. Which items do want to delay and by how long?

Comment: I want to make it automaticly. For example my list has 6 item. I want write for loop i=0 i*350 i++. But I dont know how can I write :)

Comment: Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry but its not working I'm still tryin it but it's not working

Comment: This is my code block

function checkViewport(){

 var i= 0;
    $(".animateda:in-viewport(-10)").find(".animated").each(function(queue) {
    setTimeout(function() {
 $(this).addClass($(this).attr("data-animation"));
 }, i * 350);
    i++; // increment i for each item
 });
    
}

       
function initAnimation() {
 checkViewport();
 $(window).bind("scroll", function(event) {checkViewport();}); //end scroll
 $(window).resize(function(){checkViewport();});
}

Comment: I missed a closure in my code, while I fix it, here's a suggestion nonetheless: Is the selector meant to select `.animateda:in-viewport(-10)` or should it be `.animated:in-viewport(-10)`?

Comment: No it's true animateda class is viewport and animated class for each animated item